# How To update Text box contents after a selection change in ListPicker in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-7

I have to update my `txtid` , `txtName` ,`txtAge` ,`txtContact`..OnSelectionChange of `ListPicker` , but even after selecting items it is not updating `txtfields` . How can i step up on it ?

```
public partial class Update : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        Button btnUpdate1 = null;
        TextBox txtid = null;
        TextBox txtName = null;
        TextBox txtAge = null;
        TextBox txtContact = null;
        ListPicker lp = null;
        int selectedItem ;

        public Update()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
            int x = noofrows();
            createUpdateButton();
            createListPicker();
            selectedItem = Convert.ToInt32(lp.SelectedItem);     
            createTxtId(selectedItem);
            createTxtName(selectedItem);
            createTxtAge(selectedItem);
            createTxtContact(selectedItem);

        }
        public void createListPicker()
        {
            lp = new ListPicker();            
            lp.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            lp.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            lp.Margin = new Thickness(12, 5, 0, 0);
            lp.Width = 400;
            int x = noofrows();
            for (int a = 1; a <= x; a++)
            {
                string str1 = returnID(a);
                lp.Items.Add(str1);                
            }
            lp.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                selectedItem = Convert.ToInt32(lp.SelectedItem);

            };
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(lp);    

        }
        public void createUpdateButton()
        {
            btnUpdate1 = new Button();
            btnUpdate1.Margin = new Thickness(100, 600, 0, 0);
            btnUpdate1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            btnUpdate1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            btnUpdate1.Height = 100;
            btnUpdate1.Width = 150;
            btnUpdate1.Content = "update";
            btnUpdate1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            btnUpdate1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            btnUpdate1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            btnUpdate1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            btnUpdate1.FontSize = 28;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnUpdate1);
            btnUpdate1.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                UpdateDatabase(selectedItem);
            };

        }
        public void createTxtId(int z)
        {
            int id  = z ;
            txtid = new TextBox();
            txtid.Margin = new Thickness(12, 100, 0, 0);
            txtid.Width = 400;
            txtid.Height = 100;
            txtid.FontSize = 28;
            txtid.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtid.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            txtid.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txtid.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            txtid.IsReadOnly = true;
            txtid.Text = "  " + id;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtid);

        }
        public void createTxtName(int z)
        {
            txtName = new TextBox();
            txtName.Margin = new Thickness(12, 200, 0, 0);
            txtName.Width = 400;
            txtName.Height = 100;
            txtName.FontSize = 28;
            txtName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtName.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtName.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            txtName.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txtName.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            txtName.Text = SelectName(z);
            txtName.Tap += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtName.Text == "Name")
                {
                    txtName.Text = "";
                }
            };
            txtName.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtName.Text == "")
                {
                    txtName.Text = "Name";
                }
            };
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtName);
        }
        public void createTxtAge(int z)
        {
            txtAge = new TextBox();
            txtAge.Margin = new Thickness(12, 300, 0, 0);
            txtAge.Width = 400;
            txtAge.Height = 100;
            txtAge.FontSize = 28;
            txtAge.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtAge.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtAge.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            txtAge.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txtAge.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);

            txtAge.MaxLength = 2;

            txtAge.Text = SelectAge(z);
            txtAge.InputScope = new InputScope();
            txtAge.InputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeName() { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number });
            txtAge.Tap += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtAge.Text == "Age")
                {
                    txtAge.Text = "";
                }
            };
            txtAge.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtAge.Text == "")
                {
                    txtAge.Text = "Age";
                }
            };
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtAge);
        }
        public void createTxtContact(int z)
        {
            txtContact = new TextBox();
            txtContact.Margin = new Thickness(12, 400, 0, 0);
            txtContact.Width = 400;
            txtContact.Height = 100;
            txtContact.FontSize = 28;
            txtContact.MaxLength = 10;
            txtContact.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtContact.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            txtContact.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            txtContact.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            txtContact.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
            txtContact.Text = SelectContact(z);
            txtContact.InputScope = new InputScope();
            txtContact.InputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeName() { NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number });
            txtContact.Tap += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtContact.Text == "Contact")
                {
                    txtContact.Text = "";
                }
            };
            txtContact.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (txtContact.Text == "")
                {
                    txtContact.Text = "Contact";

                }
            };
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtContact);

        }
        public Int32 noofrows()
        {
            int b = Convert.ToInt32((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList("select count(*) from details"));
            return b;
        }
        public string returnID(int z)
        {
            return Convert.ToString((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList("select id from details where id =" + z));
        }
        public String SelectName(int x)
        {
            return Convert.ToString((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList("select name from details where id =" + x));
        }
        public String SelectAge(int x)
        {
            return Convert.ToString((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList("select age from details where id =" + x));
        }
        public String SelectContact(int x)
        {
            return Convert.ToString((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList("select contact from details where id =" + x));
        }
        public void  UpdateDatabase(int ID)
        {           
            if (txtName.Text=="Name")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Name");


            }
            else if (txtAge.Text.Length>=3||txtAge.Text=="Age")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter A valid Age (1-99)");

            }
            else if (txtContact.Text.Length != 10)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Mobile number Of 10 digit");

            }
            else
            {
                string s1 = "update details set id='" + Convert.ToInt64(txtid.Text) + "', name = '" + txtName.Text + "', age = '" + txtAge.Text + "', contact = '" + txtContact.Text + "'where id = " + ID;
                string s2 = Convert.ToString((Application.Current as App).db.SelectList(s1));

                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: So much code, so many dangling event-handlers, & so many memory leaks.

Comment: thanks William for that But I am a Beginer so It happens . But I will Try To Solve it This way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this ...
Actually if we want to update that we need to change text of each text box . So after the selection change , Try it like this.

public void createListPicker()

```
    {
        lp = new ListPicker();            
        lp.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        lp.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
        lp.Margin = new Thickness(12, 5, 0, 0);
        lp.Width = 400;
        int x = noofrows();
        for (int a = 1; a <= x; a++)
        {
            string str1 = returnID(a);
            lp.Items.Add(str1);                
        }
        lp.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            selectedItem = Convert.ToInt32(lp.SelectedItem);
            txtid.Text = selectedItem.ToString();
            txtName.Text = SelectName(selectedItem);
            txtAge.Text = SelectAge(selectedItem);
            txtContact.Text = SelectContact(selectedItem);
        };
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(lp);    

    }
```

This will update Immediately after Every selection change Event .

Answer (score 1):

You are using so much code. Its would be better if you follow the MVM architecture and try to set Bind the textblocks to your viewModel. Lets consider the following scenario.

You have binded the xaml elements to selectedItem in your viewModel. Now when selectedItem's value is changed Notify event is triggered which will notify the UI and the values will automatically be updated.

I recommend you to study [viewmodel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821028.aspx) and try to implement it. Its really easy and would save you a lot of hassle.

Try implementing some [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Simple-MVVM-and-Windows-134e460f)

Hope it helps :)